# Scatter plot of images using imshow() in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot in MATLAB where the samples are gray-scale images, like this one: http://isomap.stanford.edu/web2.jpg.

I'm able do it by first calling scatter function to create the plot, and then calling image(x,y,I) for each image, where x (y) is the range in x-axis (y-axis) where the image is to be plotted in the original plot.

The problem is that "image" does not produce a good visualization of the images, but "imshow" does. However, I didn't find any argument on this function that allows me to specify where to plot the image inside another plot. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: See the second part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7168940/97160. This question is not an exact duplicate, should I post an example here?